# keep values after submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I know how I can keep my form where I have a select list is not deleted after a submit?

This is the line I use to fill the select list:

```
<% = select: search,: style, [[All, ""]] + Proyect.all (: group => "style",: order => "style"). collect {| a | [a. style a.estilo]}%>
```

please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

yeah. was very simple.

Solved with the folowing parameters added to the current line:

```
{:selected=>params[:search][:style]}
```

thus leaving

```
<% = select: search,: style, [[All, ""]] + Proyect.all (: group => "style",: order => "style"). collect {| a | [a. style a.estilo]},{:selected=>params[:search][:style]}%>
```

thanks anyway

-------------------ANNEX---------

That's right, but my solution, half good solution, because I have the problem that if the parameter still not been created?

How to do something like this:

```
{: selected => params [: search] [: style] if params [: search] [: style]! = nil}%>
```

being as follows:

```
<% = select: search,: style, [[All, ""]] + Proyect.all (: group => "style",: order => "style"). collect {| a | [a. ]},{: a.estilo style selected => params [: search] [: style] if params [: search] [: style]! = nil}%>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set what option is selected. This case the 2nd one is selected:

```
<%=  options_for_select([['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...], 2) %>
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags) for explanation